# How to set the clock in a Honda City 2018

Tags: honda, electronics, city

I've done it once before (last daylight saving change) but even with the owner's manual I can't work out how to set the clock. I've tried with both the car on and just in accessory position but following the instructions only reset the trip meters. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

1. Start with the key out of the ignition
2. Insert the key into the ignition
3. Turn the key two clicks to "On" (not "Start")
4. Using the Up/Down controls on the steering wheel, select "Settings" on the dashboard display

   - If all has gone well, you'll see "Adjust alert"
   - If something went wrong, you'll see two speed alert settings. Start again by removing the key from the ignition
5. Use Up/Down until you see "Adjust Clock"
6. Press the Select button (between Up and Down)
7. Adjust the hours with Up/Down/Select
8. Adjust the minutes with Up/Down/Select